# Drupal 7 increase a CCK Field Label character count

Tags: drupal, label, field, cck

I have a content type that is used as a questionnaire to ask about the users personal story. I read webform vs. content type. It seems that content type will work better for my needs.

I am using the questions as the label of custom fields in my content type. But, the Label field is limited to the number of character.

I can follow step by step well. Have a little familiarity with php and phpmyadmin if I have to go there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's easy to do. Just use description as your question. By default it appears light in color and small. So use CSS to format it and hide the label field. That's it. Done.